# Philosophy behind sigma: is it measurement error?

Tags: regression, residuals, gaussian-process

In Gaussian regression models, we model outcome as having some theoretical distribution which depends on the predictor values and can be described by the respective mean and standard deviation (sigma), where sigma is oftentimes described as a measurement error. Would not it make more sense to interpret sigma as sd of underlying generative process, which reflects influence of other unaccounted factors?

For example, if we analyze divorce rate and we see that less populated states have higher standard error associated with calculated estimates and the estimates would likely indeed fluctuate more eg. across time. One common interpretation is that this is due to sampling error, as we have small subset of "true population". But that is not correct as we perform estimates on data reflecting (virtually) whole population. The more plausible interpretation would be that with increasing size of the population, influence of unaccounted factors decreases and with increasing population size the effect would thus converge to some value. In other word, sigma would not be mere measurement error, such as error of measurement gadgets etc.

Comment: Why would unaccountable factor influence decrease with N? If all happy families are alike and each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way, that can scale with N.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you are right the residual error term often mixes multiple sources of variability. These can include measurement error due to how you measure (e.g. the red blood cell count would vary, if you took multiple blood draws from the same person in a short period of time, a blood pressure measuring device will have some measurement error etc.), due to things you could explain through additional terms in the model (if you had the right information, which you either don't have, or have decided to not include in the model, or possibly you don't even know this would be helpful to include), or due to inevitable variability. The latter category might be a bit debatable, if we start with arguments like "if I knew exactly the position of every atom in the universe" etc., but in practice you don't (and then there's things like decay of atoms that might genuinely be completely random).

Sometimes, it could of course really be that the residual error of a model is just the variability of measurements from your measurement device - e.g. if you repeatedly measure the weight of a cylinder of platinum-iridium that's meant to weigh 1 kg on your scales (without changing anything else in the measurement conditions).

Answer (score 8):

The answer of @Björn is fine. I just add some philosophical (and linguistic) reflection to it.

My take on this is that adopting a probabilistic model means that we decide to think of a data generating process as if it behaves as prescribed by the model. We should still keep in mind clearly that the model is in fact different from what goes on in the real world. Any connection between elements of the model and what goes on in the real world is our thought construct in the first place, and it can and should always be challenged, also by ourselves, to what extent this connection is convincing. Also there is, as Björn correctly explains, a variety of possibilities how the connection can actually be understood.

If I use a regression model for the relation of certain variables to a response, thinking about the situation in terms of this model basically means that I treat everything that deviates from the regression equation as random "noise", and the sigma quantifies the amount of such "noise". Note that by doing this, I do *not* commit to believing that what goes on in reality is indeed meaningless noise, or even an "error" in some sense. In fact the term "error" is very problematic, as it suggests that this is something that shouldn't be there, something that is in some sense erroneous and wrong, but there is no reason that in fact this is so, as the world has no reason to play by the rules of our models.

Part of a good model discussion is to make explicit what we believe (and potentially have information about) contributes to the random variation modelled by what is all too often called "error term".

"Measurement error" may be a part of this, or even the whole thing, but there could be other things such as the influence of unmeasured variables or potentially meaningful individual differences that are just too complicated to model and may behave more or less like normally distributed "noise" in terms of the data we observe.

The term "error" in "measurement error" suggests that we want to measure something that exists and has a unique true value, but we can't observe it directly, so we observe something else and call the difference "error". The use of the term "error" is more appropriate here as it is clear why this is an error (according to what we think is going on), however note that the "unique true value" is not observable and can be seen as a thought construct in itself (there is an "operational theory of measurement" that would not start the explanation of measurement by postulating the existence of such a true but unobserved value but would rather hold that what is measured is determined by the measurement procedure in the first place). Of course if we measure supposedly the same thing several times and get different results (as some measurement instruments produce), this gives some credibility to the idea that the measurement error produces something that can be treated as random variation in the model, although it may still be troublesome regarding specific assumptions such as normality or i.i.d.

I like a lot about the question the acknowledgement that what is often called "error" is very often a misnomer. I believe a more helpful way of thinking about this is to have clearly in mind the difference between model and reality. The random variation term in regression (this is how I like to call it) is implicitly imposed on the situation by our choice of modelling, and doesn't come with any specific "true" or "natural" interpretation. Rather the modeller is asked to elaborate what in their view contributes to it in the real situation (which may be measurement error but also other things), and then the question of interest for scrutinising the model are (1) are there other important influences/factors that are ignored in the model, and (2) as far as the factors the modeller is aware of are concerned, is it appropriate to model these as random variation, i.e., do they behave in such a way that any intended model interpretation will not be misleading?